# Como convertir un argumento sys.argv[1] a un string y usarlo como parametro en python?

Tags: python, electron

estoy usando Electronjs para la parte grafica  y Python como back-end.

el problema ocurre cuando paso una lista de argumentos al script de python quiero usar esos argumentos como parámetros y que los resuelva el script.py lo estoy implementando de la siguiente manera. primero llamo ala consola con la siguiente funcion desde mi html.

```
   function sendToPython() {
      var { PythonShell } = require('python-shell');
        
        var envia = $('#cars').val(); 
        var recibe = $('#cars2').val();   
        var fecha = $('#fecha').val(); 
        var fecha2 = $('#fecha2').val();    
        var options = {
        mode: 'text',
        pythonOptions: ['-u'], 
        args: [envia, recibe, fecha, fecha2]
        };
    
    
      PythonShell.run('./python/main.py', options, function (err, results) {
        if (err) throw err;
        // results is an array consisting of messages collected during execution
        console.log('results: ', results);          
        results.textContent = results[0];      

      });
   
    }
```

y en el script lo integro de la siguiente manera

```
import sys

#el error que sale dice  Error: TypeError: decoding str is not supported
envia = str(sys.argv[1], 'utf-8')
# si lo uso asi me dice  Error: TypeError: Argument must be bytes or unicode, got 'NoneType'
recibe = sys.argv[1]
```

estoy intentando asignar una variable de cadena de caracteres con el dato que trae argv[] la pregunta es como lo hago correctamente ?

intente usarlo en una funcion asi

```
import sys

# imprime bien el valor de argv[1]
print(argv[1])


# si lo uso asi me dice  Error: TypeError: Argument must be bytes or unicode
solicitud = descarga.solicitar_descarga(
    token, sys.argv[1], FECHA_INICIAL, FECHA_FINAL, receptor=sys.argv[2], tipo_solicitud='datos'
)
```

Tengo entendido que argv es un elemento lista  y que argv[0] corresponde al nombre del archivo en python. de ahi en adelante esos elementos de lista los quiero usar para guardarlos en otras variables y usarlos en el resto del script

Comment: Parece que no llega nada al primer argumento, `sys.argv[1]`. ¿Estás seguro que la variable `envia` captura algo de `#cars`?

Comment: Si ese id #cars trae un nombre guardado  que extraigo de un input text

Answer (score 2):

#### Básicamente:

String -> Bytes (usar `encode()`)

Bytes -> String (usar `decode()` o `str()`)

### Código de ejemplo

```
import sys

print('input: ',sys.argv[1],', type: ',type(sys.argv[1]))
#el error que sale dice  Error: TypeError: decoding str is not supported
envia1 = sys.argv[1].encode('UTF-8')
print('envia1: ',envia1,' ---> salida es binaria')

try:
    # Esta parte del código NO se ejecuta, por error. (recibe string)
    envia2= str(sys.argv[1],'utf-8')
    print('envia2: ',envia2,' ---> salida es ERROR')
except:
    # Esta parte del código SI se ejecuta. (recibe bytes)
    # recibe binario
    envia3= str(envia1,'utf-8')
    print('envia3: ',envia3,' ---> salida es string')

# si lo uso asi me dice  Error: TypeError: Argument must be bytes or unicode, got 'NoneType'
recibe = sys.argv[1]
print('recibe: ',recibe ,' ---> salida es string')
```

#### Resultado

```
>>input:  HelloWorld , type:  <class 'str'>
>>envia1:  b'HelloWorld'  ---> salida es binaria
>>envia3:  HelloWorld  ---> salida es string
>>recibe:  HelloWorld  ---> salida es string
```

Comment: Hola Alfredo gracias por tu ayuda no me quedo claro como usaría argv[1] en mi caso. acabo de editar mi pregunta para darle mas contexto por si gustas ver

gracias y saludos!